# Unable to style mail body using velocity template

Tags: templates, velocity

I am using velocity template to send email.
I am able to send the mail with static text as body of the mail.
But I am unable to style the mail body like adding color styling tables in the mail body.

thus could you please suggest how I can acheive.

This is sample vm file  which I am getting as it is mail body i.e it is not styled.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>User Information</title>
        <style>
            body{
                 font-family: verdana;
            }

            table {
                width: 500px;

            }

            table, th, td {
                border: 1px solid black;
                padding: 2px;
            }

            th{
                background-color: #00439A;
                color : #FFFFFF;
            }

            tr.odd{
                background-color: #CFCFCF;
            }

            tr.even{
                background-color: #1076F5;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>User Information</h1>   
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
        </tr> 
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: We would also need the Java code to be able to help you. Obviously, the problem resides in the mime type (text/plain instead of text/html).

Comment: Hi Claude, yes adding MIME type solved my problem. Thanks for the suggestion:)